# Using PDO transactions without ATTR_PERSISTENT?

Tags: php, pdo, transactions, persistent

Will transactions work as well without setting the option ATTR_PERSISTENT?
The only example in the manual implies that:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should work as Transaction has nothing to do with the type of connection you establish.